# Python, yt-dlp y Pyinstaller , ejecutable no funciona

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Tengo una aplicación que utiliza diversas librerías, entre ellas `yt-dlp`, para mostrar información de videos y descargarlos si procede.

De forma interpretada funciona todo correctamente, pero cuando lo compilo con pyinstaller, las llamadas a la clase `YoutubeDL`, provocan un error y devuelven el control a la pantalla principal que originó el proceso.

NO DA NINGUN MENSAJE DE ERROR POR NINGUN SITIO, simplemente no ejecuta la función e interrumpe el flujo normal.

La llamada está dentro de un Try/Exception , pero no capta la excepción.

Se que sucede esto porque tengo un log que recoge los pasos por donde va el programa y justo antes de la llamada a `youtubeDL` lo recoge el log y después se pierde todo el hilo.

El código que uso es:

```
class Ytdlp:
def __init__(self,ventana,etiqueta,boton):
    # Clase para gestionar yt-dlp con acceso a la venta principal
    self.ventana = ventana   # ventana principal desde la cual se instancia la clase
    self.boton=boton          #boton de descargar para gestionar que este habilitado, desde aqui
    self.info_diccionario={}
    self.ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'best',
    } 
def get_video_info(self,url):
    
    logging.info(f'dentro de get_video_info({url})')
    retorno=True
    try:
        
        with YoutubeDL(self.ydl_opts) as ydl:
            self.info_diccionario = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        if  self.info_diccionario==None:
            logging.ERROR('ydl.extract_info({url},download=false) retorna {self.info_diccionario}')
            retorno=False
        else:
            logging.info(f"Título del video: {self.info_diccionario.get('title', '')}")
    except Exception as error:
         logging.ERROR(f'extract info produce el error: {Exception}')
         retorno=False
    return retorno
```

Y lo que aparece en el log, es:

```
2023-06-28 11:32:14,670 - INFO - Directorio de la aplicación: (C:\Users\Ramon\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI148162)2023-06-28 11:32:14,728 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
2023-06-28 11:32:14,728 - DEBUG - STREAM b'sBIT' 41 4
2023-06-28 11:32:14,728 - DEBUG - b'sBIT' 41 4 (unknown)
2023-06-28 11:32:14,728 - DEBUG - STREAM b'pHYs' 57 9
2023-06-28 11:32:14,728 - DEBUG - STREAM b'tEXt' 78 25
2023-06-28 11:32:14,728 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IDAT' 115 8192
2023-06-28 11:32:14,742 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
2023-06-28 11:32:14,742 - DEBUG - STREAM b'sRGB' 41 1
2023-06-28 11:32:14,742 - DEBUG - STREAM b'gAMA' 54 4
2023-06-28 11:32:14,742 - DEBUG - STREAM b'pHYs' 70 9
2023-06-28 11:32:14,742 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IDAT' 91 65445
2023-06-28 11:32:14,754 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
2023-06-28 11:32:14,754 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IDAT' 41 8192
2023-06-28 11:32:14,756 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - STREAM b'PLTE' 41 633
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - STREAM b'tRNS' 686 1
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - STREAM b'bKGD' 699 1
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - b'bKGD' 699 1 (unknown)
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - STREAM b'pHYs' 712 9
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - STREAM b'tIME' 733 7
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - b'tIME' 733 7 (unknown)
2023-06-28 11:32:14,757 - DEBUG - STREAM b'IDAT' 752 7705
2023-06-28 11:32:36,436 - DEBUG -  ytdlp.get_video_info(https://youtu.be/ToDcjnxouQU)
2023-06-28 11:32:36,436 - INFO - dentro de get_video_info(https://youtu.be/ToDcjnxouQU)
```

He compilado con las siguientes opciones:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "D:\Programacion\Python\\MyApp\images;images" --icon=images\AI_128px_8bits.ico -paths=D:\Python\Lib\site-packages foo.pyw
```

¿que debería hacer para obtener una aplicación, mejor un solo ejecutable que funcione en cualquier plataforma Windows, aunque no tenga Python?.

NOTA. La aplicación `yt-dlp` tiene su propio systema de auto-compilación con pyinstaller y un par de scripts, que resultan en un ejecutable plenamente funcional, por tanto es posible, pero no sé como aplicar este conocimiento en mi provecho.

Comment: Cual es el error que te aparece? Si lo agregas a la pregunta, será más facil ayudarte.

Comment: Perdón, no da ningún error, ni mensaje ni nada. Quería decir que se interrumpe el flujo en la llamada a la librería externa y ya está.

Comment: No pasa nada c: Podrías publicar una muestra de código en el que ocurra eso por favor? (no es necesario que sea el original). Algo que se me pasa por la cabeza, es que estés tratando de capturar mensajes de log. Pero en realidad, esos no serían excepciones. Por lo que el try-except no los captura. También podrías probar quitando -windowed para ver la consola y ver que sucede.

Comment: Solo para aclarar el lenguaje de tu pregunta, PyInstaller no compila, nunca lo hace. Tu programa siempre corre _interpretado_, en el sentido que siempre hay un interprete de python analizando y ejecutando el script en tiempo de corrida. Más información en [What PyInstaller Does and How It Does It](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html). Sugiero que muestres cómo _capturas_ la excepción y cómo llevas el log, para ver si así surge una idea de qué puede hacerse para llegar a la fuente del error.

Comment: He quitado --windowed , pero no aparece ningún mensaje en la consola, de ningun tipo

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración respecto a compilar, estaba confundido. He modificado mi pregunta original,  incorporando el código que utilizo y la respuesta del log

Comment: Escribiste ERROR en mayuscula, no sería todo en minuscula? Además, ejecuta tu exe desde cmd para ver el error. Si no, la consola se cierra antes de que puedas ver el error.

Comment: Lo primero es que escribí "ERROR" que es un "enum" en lugar de "error" que es lo correcto. De repente el programa si que devuelve un error: "class 'Exception'

Comment: Lo segundo es que mi script principal tenia la extensión pyw y eso implica windowed aunque al "empaquetar" se indique lo contrario y es por esto que no devolvía ninguna información a consola

Comment: TERCERO y mas importante , YT-DLP debe necesitar de la consola obligatoriamente, puesto que ahora todo funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias, desde luego sin vuestra ayuda jamás lo habría encontrado

Answer (score 0):

Tenía varios errores, uno de concepto, otro de sintaxis y otro de desconocimiento.
El problema principal es que YT-DLP debe de necesitar la consola de forma obligatoria y si no la encuentra, falla retornando un "class exception".
Así que no se puede utilizar la opción --windowed a la hora de empaquetar y tampoco se puede utilizar la extensión *.pyw en el script, porque eso implica no consola y volvemos al punto anterior.

Muchas gracias a los compañeros que me han guiado hasta la solución.